# SKSpriteKit : How to detect "touches began" for custom SKSpiteNode "buttons"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

I created a class for creating buttons in my app.

The code for the Button class is like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class SKButtons: SKSpriteNode {

var sprtButton : SKSpriteNode

    init(image strImageName : String) {

        let texture : SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: strImageName)

        sprtButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: strImageName)

        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

This button is used in my GameScene (inherit from SKScene) where I want to detect the touches began events when the button is touched. The simplified code of the GameScene is like this:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {}
//
// 
    let btnControl1 = SKButtons(image: "button")
    btnControl1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    btnControl1.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    btnControl1.zPosition = 3
    btnControl1.name = "btnControl1"
    self.addChild(btnControl1)
//
//
```

And the touches began function,

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for t in touches {

            let cgPointTouched = t.location(in: self)
            let skNodeTouched : SKNode = self.atPoint(cgPointTouched)

            switch skNodeTouched.name {

            case "btnControl1":

                print("btnControl1 touched")

            default:
                return

            }   
        }
    }
```

I placed a breakpoint in the touches began func and it did not fire.

So, how do I make my touches began function which is in the GameScene, fire when a button placed it in is touched. The button is a class of SKSpriteNode.

Thanks.

Comment: That's probably because you are touching something on top of it.

Comment: @ElTomato: If i replace let btnControl1 = SKButtons(image: "button") with let btnControl1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button") then the touches began will be fired.

Comment: In my code for the Button class, I missed out "isUserInteractionEnabled = true" when posting my question.

Comment: You want `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to false if your touch code is going to be in the scene class

Comment: Thanks. I commented the "isUserInteractionEnabled" and it worked. Why is this so?

Comment: because `isUserInteractionEnabled` means that the touchesBegan gets processed by that instance, not the scene.  If you overrode the touchesBegan in your SKButtons class, then you wouldn't need your code in your scene class.  Of course, if you pressed into the SKButton, then pressed out on the scene, then your began would be called in SKButton, and your ended would be called in your GameScene, which may not be desirable